# Problem entering the boot screen on HP Laptop

Tags: boot

I want to install Windows on a HP laptop. The laptop doesn't boot from the DVD, and I have tried to open the boot screen to enable booting from the DVD, but I can't do that. I've tried:

- Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- Pressing <kbd>F8</kbd>
- Pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>
- Pressing <kbd>Del</kbd>

None of these keys are working. Any ideas how I can enter the boot screen on my laptop?

Comment: Always put the model in a model-specific question. We can guess, but with a model, we could tell you exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Other common keys to get into the BIOS are F1, F2, F10, or even F9. For HP, I would try F10 (most common for HP), then F1 first.

Comment: yeah, just try all FX buttons :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the one time boot menu has been disabled.

Simply go in to the BIOS (or EFI) and change the boot order there. I can't give specifics as it is quite different on every BIOS (or EFI).

You simply need to reorder so that the optical drive boots before the hard drive.

Remember to change it back after otherwise your machine will take a few extra seconds to boot.